# Insert JS Snippet To WP Site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've been slowly truing to teach myself some simple aspects regarding coding. Right now, I want to upload a snippet of JS code onto a single page. Here is some background followed with the code I want to use:

The code will go on one page. This page is a form page where if someone does anything other than press "submit" a module pops up with some questions. I've been using wordpress. Any thoughts, guidance, etc. would be perfecto!

```
<script>
            var config = new Object();
            config.surveyID = 3160325;
            /*config.animationMode = 0;*/
            config.takeSurveyURL = 'http://www.surveyanalytics.com/a/TakeSurvey';
            config.windowPositionLeft = 200;
            config.windowPositionTop = 300;
            config.home = 'http://www.surveyanalytics.com/';
            config.isRightToLeft = false;
            config.surveyStartMessage = 'Start Survey';
            config.popupInvitationLaterMessage = 'Later';
            config.showFooter = true;
            config.invitationDelay = 0;
            config.skipCount = 0;
            config.popupMode = 0;
            config.expirationTime = 60
               window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                        QP_popupMain();
               };
        </script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.surveyanalytics.com//javascript/exitSurveyInvitation.js"></script>
            <noscript>

            <a href="http://www.supporterfeedback.org/a/TakeSurvey?id=3160325">Start Survey</a>  <a href="http://www.surveyanalytics.com/">Survey</a>

            </noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress doesn't like `<script>` tags within functions.php, instead put your code into a ".js" file and register the script in functions.php and then enqueue it in your shortcode.

In your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_script' );

function register_my_script() {
    //This example puts it in plugins, but you can put it in your theme instead
    wp_register_script( 'script-name', plugins_url( '/js/script.js' , __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

//Replace "PUT YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE IN HERE" with your actual code
function myTestFunction( $atts )
{
    //Now enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name' );
}

add_shortcode( 'myjavascriptfunction', 'myTestFunction' );
```

Then in the CMS, go to that page and add the call to the shortcode in the content text box:

```
[myjavascriptfunction /]
```

Comment: Thank you! Anywhere in particular in the functions.php file - currently I'm receiving:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'javascript' (T_STRING) in /home2/brady/public_html/demo/wp-content/themes/DonateNow/functions.php on line 615

Comment: It's not liking the following: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.surveyanalytics.com//javascript/exitSurveyInvitation.js"></script>

Comment: @CyberClown Try my new code. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Don - now one last question as I think this is the root of the problem. The function reference / plugins url is assuming that you're referencing the Wp_content folder on the main domain, but I'm trying to incorporate this to a sub domain. How would I go about setting up that up?

Comment: @CyberClown can you explain what you mean? do you mean sub directory or sub domain?

Comment: it's a subdomain - the my understanding is that plugins_url() is essentially saying wp-content/plugins/script.js.  However I setting this up on a sub domain and my script.js file is located at demo/wp-content/plugins/script.js

Comment: @CyberClown plugins_url takes care of that for you. read the documentation

Comment: Ok - do I need to change any variables above then? I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: Posted it as an answer because of character limit

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in script.js

```
 <script>
                var config = new Object();
                config.surveyID = 3160325;
                /*config.animationMode = 0;*/
                config.takeSurveyURL = 'http://www.surveyanalytics.com/a/TakeSurvey';
                config.windowPositionLeft = 200;
                config.windowPositionTop = 300;
                config.home = 'http://www.surveyanalytics.com/';
                config.isRightToLeft = false;
                config.surveyStartMessage = 'Start Survey';
                config.popupInvitationLaterMessage = 'Later';
                config.showFooter = true;
                config.invitationDelay = 0;
                config.skipCount = 0;
                config.popupMode = 0;
                config.expirationTime = 60
                   window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                            QP_popupMain();
                   };
            </script>

            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.surveyanalytics.com//javascript/exitSurveyInvitation.js"></script>
                <noscript>

                <a href="http://www.supporterfeedback.org/a/TakeSurvey?id=3160325">Start Survey</a>  <a href="http://www.surveyanalytics.com/">Survey</a>

                </noscript>
```

This is the code in function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_script' );

function register_my_script() {
    //This example puts it in plugins, but you can put it in your theme instead
    wp_register_script( 'script', plugins_url( '/script.js/' , __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

//Replace "PUT YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE IN HERE" with your actual code
function myTestFunction( $atts )
{
    //Now enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );
}

add_shortcode( 'myjavascriptfunction', 'myTestFunction' );
```

Comment: you don't use script tags in a script file